# Getting too many rows when joining tables

Tags: sql

I don't understand why I'm getting so many rows when doing a select statement. Both queries should return 7017 rows.

When I do this statement, I get 7017 rows:

```sql
SELECT playerID, yearid, teamid, B2 * 2 + B3 * 3 + HR * 4 + BB + H AS TotalBasesTouched
FROM BATTING
WHERE teamID IN ('NYA','NYN');
```

I should also get 7017 rows here too, but instead I get 654,645. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```sql
SELECT distinct batting.playerID, batting.yearid, batting.teamid, 
batting.B2 * 2 + batting.B3 * 3 + batting.HR * 4 + batting.BB + batting.H AS Total_Bases_Touched
,franchID
,Teams.B2 * 2 + Teams.B3 * 3 + teams.HR * 4 + teams.BB + teams.H AS Teams_Bases_Touched
,format((batting.B2 * 2.0 + batting.B3 * 3.0 + batting.HR * 4.0 + batting.BB + batting.H) / 
(teams.B2 * 2.0 + teams.B3 * 3.0 + teams.HR * 4.0 + teams.BB + teams.H),'P') as 'Touched_%'

FROM Batting, Teams
WHERE batting.teamid IN ('NYA', 'NYN') and batting.teamid = teams.teamid;
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: How many records do you get from `SELECT * FROM teams WHERE teamid IN ('NYA', 'NYN')`?

Comment: The result is every pairing of a row from the first table with a row from the second table. The number of rows in the result is therefore the product of the number of rows in the original tables. Its Kind f cartesian product between tables. Using join will be the better option.

Comment: I get 177 rows with SELECT * FROM teams WHERE teamid IN ('NYA', 'NYN')

Comment: I would use a JOIN, but I have to use FROM BATTING, TEAMS and join in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Note:** the `franchid` did not reference a table so I assumed it was t.franchid. Your `JOIN` statement was in your `WHERE` clause which will cause issues.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     b.playerID
    ,b.yearid
    ,b.teamid
    ,b.B2 * 2 + b.B3 * 3 + b.HR * 4 + b.BB + b.H AS Total_Bases_Touched
    ,t.franchID
    ,t.B2 * 2 + t.B3 * 3 + t.HR * 4 + t.BB + teams.H AS Teams_Bases_Touched
    ,FORMAT((b.B2 * 2.0 + b.B3 * 3.0 + b.HR * 4.0 + b.BB + b.H) 
      / 
      (t.B2 * 2.0 + t.B3 * 3.0 + t.HR * 4.0 + t.BB + t.H),'P') AS 'Touched_%'

FROM Batting AS b
JOIN Teams AS t
ON b.teamid = t.teamid

WHERE b.teamid IN ('NYA', 'NYN');
```

Comment: Same number of rows returned. Batting AS b and Teams AS T is a handy tool though. In this case I have to joing the tables in the WHERE clause. Not allowed to use JOIN ON

Comment: can you elaborate as to why you have to join the tables in the where clause?

Comment: It's part of a HW assignment for a SQL class.  I've put a few hours into it and have successfully joined smaller tables, but can't get anywhere with this.

Comment: If I add in an order by player_id, I can see that the Teams_Bases_Touched comes out in many different values for the same player so I think that's where my problem is.

Comment: Your curious how a players “bases touched “ compares to the teams for a given year. You do this by adding the Teams table to the query (Slide 24) and calculating a Teams_Bases_Touched columns using the same formula for the H, HR, BB, B2 and B3 columns in the teams table. You also want to know the percentage of the teams touched bases each payer was responsible for. Calculated the Touched_% column and use the FORMAT statement for show the results as a % and with commas  (Slide 20 and 29). Only

Comment: select the 2 NY teams, the Yankees and the Mets  (Teamid equals NYA or NYN) so that only the information for the NY teams is returned. Write your query with a FROM statement that uses the format FROM BATTING,TEAMS. Your query should return 7,017 rows. The FROM parameter should be in the format FROM table1,table2 and the join parameters need to be in the WHERE parameter.

Comment: Question is above if that adds any context. The join is probably working fine, but I messed up the Teams_Based_Touched somehow.

Comment: Confirmed that the Teams_Based_Touched has multiple unique values when it shouldn't. For a single player that should have 1 row, I'm getting 118 rows with unique values only for Teams_Based_Touched.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to join the tables on the teamID **AND yearID**